# dummy "it" and the the verb "make"

Tags: grammar, verbs, infinitive-clauses, dummy-pronouns

I really want to know about the relation between dummy "it" and the the verb "make".

These example sentences are from TOEFL, and I collected all of them which includes dummy "it" after the verb "make".

1. A well-kept room *making* **it** possible for people to concentrate effectively on their work.
2. Orderly environment *makes* **it** easier to process the information, which ensures that tasks are completed more efficiently.
3. The rise in demand for domestic goods causes local companies to increase production, which *makes* **it** necessary to hire more workers.
4. It is the lack or gravity on the moon that *makes* **it** possible to leap 30feet or more.
5. More and more people are *making changes* to their lifestyle that are beneficial to the environment.

When I googled about the *dummy it* after the verb *make*, it said that **it** has to be the subject of an *infinitive phrase*.

However, according to the Cambridge Dictionary, https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/infinitives-and-imperatives/infinitives-with-and-without-to,

it is written that we can use the *to infinitive* in a clause with a verb that has no subject.

Moreover, *example number 5*, the sentence is grammatical even if verb *make* is used without *dummy* **it**.

now I am in panic...

Several days I have looked up dictionary and google, but I do not get the right answer..

please help me to understand the syntactic structure regarding **make** and **dummy it** with infinitive clause.

Answer (score 1):

In 1-4, *it* stands for an infinitive verb phrase that appears later in the sentence.

They are:

1. "to concentrate effectively on their work"
2. "to process the information"
3. "to hire more workers"
4. "to leap 30 feet or more"

To avoid the dummy *it*; one could replace it with the gerund version of each of these phrases, like so:

1. A well-kept room makes **concentrating effectively on their work** possible for people.
2. An orderly environment makes **processing the information** easier, which ensures that tasks are completed more efficiently.
3. The rise in demand for domestic goods causes local companies to increase production, which makes **hiring more workers** necessary.
4. It is the lack or gravity on the moon that makes **leaping 30 feet or more** possible.

However, using the dummy *it* and moving the verb phrase later makes these sentences more easily readable. In particular, number 1 moves the verb "concentrating" much closer to "people", who are the ones concentrating, making it much easier to parse.

Your 5th example is not the same use of the word *make*. The verb *make* is used with *changes* or *a change* to indicate who is causing the change. For example,  the same use of *make* appears in this sentence: *I made changes*.